# Python dictionary for output command handling

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get below output to variable "node_info"

```
Node: node1
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000
1 entries found
```

I want check the status of the Port, Link, and MTU

I was using below method:

```
def mkdict(din):
    global d
    d = {}
    for line in din.split("\n"):
        if ":" not in line:
                continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value
mkdict(node_info)
Port = "a0a-180"
Link = "up"
MTU = "9000"

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == "Port":
        v = v.strip()
        if v.lower() == Port.lower():
             print "Port is {}".format(v)
        else:
             print "Failed:Port is {}".format(v)

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == "Link":
        v = v.strip()
        if v.lower() == Link.lower():
             print "Link is {}".format(v)
        else:
             print "Failed:Link is {}".format(v)
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == "MTU":
        v = v.strip()
        if v.lower() == MTU.lower():
             print "MTU is {}".format(v)
        else:
             print "Failed:MTU is {}".format(v)
```

Now I am getting below output to variable "node_info"

```
Node: node1
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000

Node: node2
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000

Node: node3
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000

Node: node4
Port: a0a-180
Link: up    
MTU: 9000
4 entries found.
```

Since keys are repeatable and Node key also repeating. How to check my output for all 4 nodes (node1 to node4). I May get output some times more than 64 nodes.

Note: actual output of node is like below but i want to check only Port, MTU, Linux hence i provided above info in output .

```
Node: node1
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000
status: online
Mac: 00:0a:0c:0a:00:01 
Mode: RW
Type: 10G
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a struct like this?

```
{key=node_name, value={port:port_val,link:link_val,mtu:mtu_val,status:status_val}}
```

BTW, what do you mean by this ***Node key also repeating***? You mean that maybe the node_name(e.g: node1) may appears more than once in your input file?

If so, I think it depends on your demands, as I think, for one single node, all the port value, MTU value, etc, should have only one value, so if you get two nodes named node1, what's the accurate value of this node?

Code:

```
data = dict()

with open("source.txt", 'r') as fr:
    while(True):
        line = fr.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        else:
            tmp_array = line.strip().split(":")
            if len(tmp_array) != 2:
                continue
            else:
                key = tmp_array[0]
                value = tmp_array[1]
            if key == "Node":
                node_name = value
                if value not in data:
                    data[value] = dict()
            else:
                if node_name:
                    data[node_name][key] = value

res_num = 0
Port = "a0a-180"
Link = "up"
MTU = "9000"

for key, value in data.iteritems():
    flag = True
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        if k == "Port":
            if v.strip() != Port:
                print "Failed:{} Port is {}".format(key, v)
                flag = False
        if k == "Link":
            if v.strip() != Link:
                print "Failed:{} Link is {}".format(key, v)
                flag = False
        if k == "MTU":
            if v.strip() != MTU:
                print "Failed:{} MTU is {}".format(key, v)
                flag = False
    if flag:
        res_num += 1

print "{} entries found".format(res_num)
```

Here is the sample input file:

```
Node: node1
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000

Node: node2
Port: a0a-180
Link: down
MTU: 9000

Node: node3
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000

Node: node4
Port: a0a-180
Link: up
MTU: 9000
```

And the output is like:

```
Failed: node2 Link is  down
3 entries found
```

Comment: node_name key is name and value is different ex: node: node1, node: node2, Here key is same and value is changing

Comment: So why don't you directly use the node_name as the key and put all other values in a dictionary as a value?

Comment: Yes, you are true but i am searching this method of example i am not getting. could you please provide me example how to do that

Comment: I think it's okay, but what's the content in the d dictionary? As I'm not very sure the format that your data stored in your dict.

Comment: As you said make node1, node2, node3 and so on as key. Need to store respective values. If i take node1 example here. Node1 is a key and values  are Port, Link and MTU its respective output . The goal is i want to check node1 values of Port, Link and MTU are correct. for Port it should be a0a-180, for link it should up and for mtu 9000 ..like this for every node

Comment: Thanks a lot it works like charm. could you please explain these lines.if value not in data:
                    data[value] = dict()
            else:
                if node_name:
                    data[node_name][key] = value

Comment: Here value="node1" / "node2" as I mentioned above, here I use the node name as key in the dictionary, e.g: Node:node1 -> {Node:node1} here node1 is value, and I use it as key in the dictionary {node1:{port:xxxx, Link:yyyy, MTU:zzzz}}

Comment: that is great!.